# Python matplotlib X tick positions when X and Y are Matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I'm having a major problem that I can't seem to find any solution.
Basically, I am plotting a **2D field** with pcolormesh from the **matplotlib tools**.

Now, If I want to plot the 2D field, with X and Y being my X and Y dimensions and C being my matrix that I want to plot with pcolormesh, all I have to do is: (Please note that the following code is a big simplification of my actual code)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
number_of_ticks=10  # Insert number of ticks wanted

#'Insert here a non pertinent section of 1000 lines of code where I Access the data to my '
 #'variable C and my dimensions X and Y, 
 #'All we need to know is that X and Y are arrays, and C is a Matrix' 

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,12),squeeze= False)
given_positions=np.linspace(min(X),max(X),number_of_ticks)
# Un necessary section here where I create a new array 'axticklatlonname', 
#which are the names for the 10 ticks that I created earlier with given_positions
new_tick_location=given_positions
ax.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax.set_xticklabels(axticklatlonname)
mycmap=get_cmap('Jet')
mycmap.set_over('b')
col=ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,C,norm=LogNorm(vmin=-60,vmax=10),cmap=mycmap,shading='flat')
cbar=fig.colorbar(col,ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('TT')
cbar_ax=fig.add_axes
```

Until now, it works and it produces the result that I want.

My problem is that my dimension Y is actually also a variable; my heights depends on my position on the X axis.

This means that the plot will change, because of the Y positions in the C matrix are not constant for each X position anymore.

I solved this problem by changing my Y array to a matrix, and by changing my X array to a matrix with Y equivalent X arrays;

```
Xmatrix=np.tile(X(len(Y),1))
```

Now I can plot with pcolormesh:

```
col=ax.pcolormesh(Xmatrix,Ymatrix,C,norm=LogNorm(vmin=-60,vmax=10),cmap=mycmap,shading='flat')
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to specify my X tick positions.

I tried to get the default X tick position value by doing:
`ax.get_position()`
And I got as an output   Bbox([[0.125, 0.244], [0.9, 0.324]]))
This doesn't tell me much how I should specify my Xtick position.

Does someone know how to deal with Bbox, or a simple way to specify those ticks?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer,

was actually quite simple.
When X and Y are Matrix, pcolormesh actually sees the axes in form of index.

Instead of setting my X tick positions between [min(X),max(X)], I only had to fix them between  [0,len(X)]